# Error upgrade mysql server (2013 Lost connection)

Tags: 16.04, mysql, webserver

I'm trying to upgrade my MySQL Server, but I view this error when I Upgrade the server.

1- `apt-get update`

2- `apt-get upgrade`

3- Error

[image]

Server version: `Ubuntu 16.04`